# How should I create a patch from a git tree?

Tags: github, patch

I have the following git for KDGB:
[http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/jwessel/kgdb.git/refs/tags][1], each tag it the git as a complete linux source (not just a diff), while I actually need just to apply a diff to my kernel (2.6.37 #4).

Can anyone please explain what is the process of applying a patch from such git to kernel, i.e. what should I do ?

Another thing I would like to ask: is version 2.6.37 #4 (string I get from uname -a) means that I should use patch 2.6.37 or 2.6.37-rc4 ?

Best Regards,
Ran

Answer (score 1):

[git format-patch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) can be used to make patches from git source trees.

Although I don't see a kgdb tag matching your kernel version.

For your second question, '2.6.37 #4' refers to the fourth local compile of kernel version 2.6.37.

Comment: There is a tag named "2.6.37", isn't it exactly fit to my version ?
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/jwessel/kgdb.git/tag/?id=v2.6.37

Comment: That's the vanilla Linux tag, not a kgdb tag.

Comment: Thanks... so how can I find a patch to 2.6.37 ? ?

Comment: Googling suggests that KGDB is part of 2.6.37.